# Adding and Removing items from UL generated from Objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an item from a UL when the item is clicked. However, I also want to display the item at the top, then when the item is clicked return it back to the list.

AS illustrated in the screenshot below, if Item 1 is clicked, then move it to the top and remove it from the list of items to select then add it back when another item is clicked.

[image]

The list will then look like this:

[image]

I need to indicate the item was selected but also remove it from the available items to select then add it back when another item is clicked.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Amplitude/y1j9vqu8/1/):

And the code I have:

```
(function(){

    let array =
        [
            {"Item": "Select User", "ItemId": 0},
            {"Item": "Michael Jordan", "ItemId": 1},
            {"Item": "Robert Williamson", "ItemId": 2},
            {"Item": "Daniel Plainfield", "ItemId": 3}
        ];

    let nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.setAttribute("id", "menu");

    function generateList(array) {

        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){

            let li = document.createElement('li');
            let content = document.createTextNode(array[i].ItemId + " " + array[i].Item);

            li.appendChild(content);

            // Hide all except first item.
            if(i > 0){
                li.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
             }

            ul.appendChild(li);
        }

        return ul;
    }

    function bindEventToList(){

        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

        var li = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');

        li[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){

            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            // Skip the first li
            for(let i = 1; i < li.length; i ++){

                li[i].classList.toggle('hide');

                //Bind events to rest of li
                li[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){

                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                    li[0].innerText = "You Selected: "  + e.currentTarget.innerText;


                    for(let i = 1; i < li.length; i ++) {
                        li[i].classList.toggle('hide');
                    }

                }, false)
            }

        }, false);
    }

    nav.appendChild(generateList(array));
    bindEventToList();

})();
```

Comment: instead of using class, can't you just remove the node from the dom?

Comment: But how do you add it back when another item is clicked?

Comment: hide/show it. Provided the list is fixed, I see no reason to create an extra work for yourself.

Comment: I am not sure to understand because your jsfiddle seems to be already doing what you want. When you click on top, the element gets inserted back properly. Is it to have the list showed all the time but with the missing element (which figures on the "top") ?

Comment: I think I understood: "the list will look like this" is what you observe and not what you want. what you want is the list to only contain Robert and Daniel. Is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure with your requirement and your feedback is not the fastest so I may not answer to your question. In [fiddle0](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4xm70f) I rewrote a few syntaxic elements. in [fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4xm70f/1) I removed useless listeners. in [fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4xm70f/2) I applied what I understand of your requirement. is fiddle2 doing the intended behaviour?

Comment: If the item is clicked and currently the active item, then that item should not be listed below because you already selected it. If A was selected, then A should no longer be an option. If B is selected, put A back and remove B.

Comment: I thus answered your requirement in fiddle2. I am too lazy to write a proper answer though. If things are still not clear I will write one so you can comment on it

Comment: Okay, I modify the code to hide all except first li on initial load.
If you want to post the code here then I cam mark as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
    (function() {

      let array = [{
          "Item": "Select User",
          "ItemId": 0
        },
        {
          "Item": "Michael Jordan",
          "ItemId": 1
        },
        {
          "Item": "Robert Williamson",
          "ItemId": 2
        },
        {
          "Item": "Daniel Plainfield",
          "ItemId": 3
        }
      ];

      let nav = document.getElementById('nav');
      let ul = document.createElement('ul');
      ul.setAttribute("id", "menu");

      function generateList(array) {

        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

          let li = document.createElement('li');
          let content = document.createTextNode(array[i].ItemId + " " + array[i].Item);

          li.appendChild(content);

          // Hide all except first item.
          if (i > 0) {
            li.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
          }

          ul.appendChild(li);
        }

        return ul;
      }



      function bindEventToList() {

        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

        var li = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');

        var lastIndex = 0;

        li[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

          e.stopImmediatePropagation();

          // Skip the first li
          for (let i = 1; i < li.length; i++) {

            if (i !== lastIndex) {
              li[i].style.display = 'block';
            }

            //Bind events to rest of li
            li[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

              e.stopImmediatePropagation();

              li[0].innerText = "You Selected: " + e.currentTarget.innerText;

              li[i].style.display = 'none';

                            lastIndex = i;

              for (let j = 1; j < li.length; j++) {
                li[j].style.display = 'none';
              }

            }, false)
          }

        }, false);
      }

      nav.appendChild(generateList(array));
      bindEventToList();

    })();
```

---

First Try:

Quick and dirty solution:

```
e.path[0].parentNode.removeChild(e.path[0]);
```

place it somewhere in
`li[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {` function.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to toggle the item removed, meaning when another item is clicked, I want to add the removed item back.
Technically I could have also done:  `menu.removeChild(e.currentTarget)` but removing is easy, adding it back is where things are stuck.

Comment: @Asynchronous: I edited my Answer. This should work. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. This throws an error in IE because the the index at 4 is null.
`Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it in jsfiddle with chrome, firefox and edge. https://jsfiddle.net/brandtCodes/czdr79b4/42/
It works without errors.

If the error is only in a specific IE version, it should be another question I think.

Comment: It does not work in IE 11. However, I simply wrapped the affected line in an if statement to solve the problem. 

`if(li[i] !== undefined){
  li[i].style.display = 'none';
  }`